# Possibly non-conformant code generation when dealing with array accesses

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

For following simple representative code

```
int foo()
{
    extern int i;
    extern int a[];
    int sum = 0;
    sum += a[i + 10];
    sum += a[i + 20];

    return sum;
}
```

Code generated by LLVM looks like

```
movl    a+40(,%eax,4), %eax
...
movl    a+80(,%eax,4), %eax
```

Is this code really conformant to C/C++ standard?

Shouldn't generated code compute `a + (40 + eax * 4)` instead of `(a + 40) + (eax * 4)` given C/C++ defines address arithmetic only if computed address falls in same array object ?

In above case it might happen `a + 40` falls outside array however `a + (40 + eax * 4)` can still be in same array (if "i" holds negative value).

Comment: You don't have any arrays here. All you have is a pointer. The compiler cannot know whether that pointer points to an array.

Comment: The address arithmetic that works in compiler takes into account the type of the pointer. I don't think that type information is available in assembly code. In assembly code, the actual bytes must take into account the size of the type computed by the compiler.

Comment: There is no observable difference between the two methods of computing the address.

Comment: Surely a compiler just converts ASCII to binary that works on the processor. It can use whatever mechanism it sees fit. Anyway why is this a problem?

Comment: @juanchopanza what? `a` is an array.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not in C++. It is just a pointer. In C++ an array has a size, which is part of the type.

Comment: No, it is an array in C++. Array types can be incomplete. If it were a pointer, you could do `sizeof` on it. Also, it is undefined behaviour to write `extern int *a` (if `a` is defined as an array). Arrays and pointers are different. See `[dcl.array]p4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard defines the behaviour of C++ programs. This behaviour is implemented by compilers in whatever way they choose.

The restriction for pointers to only point into a single array only exists for C++ code; it may or may not hold for the language that the compiler translates the C++ into, but even if it does, this restriction is defined by the new (assembly usually) language, rather than by C++.

Answer (score 2):

There is no C/C++ standard for assembly code, so the question you are asking is incoherent. The only thing that matters, as far as the C/C++ standards are concerned, is whether the assembly code will produce the behavior required by the standard if the C/C++ source code is strictly conformant to those standards. If you believe it won't, you haven't explained why you believe that.

Answer (score 1):

> C/C++ defines address arithmetic only if computed address falls in same array object ?

That's true. It means that the behaviour is undefined if you access outside of the bounds of `a[]`.

I don't know how you get from that to conclude that "the code is not conformant". The code conforms if it turns out that `a` is the right size so that `a[i+10]` and `a[i+20]` are not out of bounds of `a`, otherwise it doesn't

If those are out of bounds of `a` then the behaviour is undefined, which means you cannot complain about whatever code the compiler emits in that case.

> In above case it might happen a + 40 falls outside array however a + (40 + eax * 4) can still be in same array (if "i" holds negative value).

That doesn't matter, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there is nothing in the standard that says exactly what the compiler should do, as long as it produces the correct result.

In your case it is optimising the calculation by making `a+40` into a constant value (once the code is translated to machine-code it will be a constant) rather than using a longer form of the instruction or worse using a second register just to add the constant 40. If `i` is negative, it will be subtracted from the address. Whether you calculate that as `(a+40) + -5*4` or `a + (40 + -5*4)` won't make any difference.

Note that if you use 64-bit mode, the compiler will generate code to sign-extend the index first, e.g:

```
movl    i(%rip), %eax
leal    10(%rax), %ecx
addl    $20, %eax
movslq  %eax, %rdx
movslq  %ecx, %rcx
movl    a(,%rcx,4), %eax
addl    a(,%rdx,4), %eax
ret
```

Here's the difference if we change `i` to be `unsigned`:

```
movl    i(%rip), %eax
leal    20(%rax), %edx
leal    10(%rax), %ecx
movl    a(,%rcx,4), %eax
addl    a(,%rdx,4), %eax
ret
```

Note the extra `movslq` instruction, which sign-extends the 32-bit `int` value to a 64-bit value.

(I wasn't able to generate exactly the same set of instructions as you show in the example, but I didn't try ALL combinations of options, and you didn't state which version of clang you are using - I'm only guessing you are using 32-bit mode, since that seems to match my results better than the 64-bit results. If the code you posted is from a 64-bit compiler, it's almost certainly a bug)